# Select last entry of all primary keys in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to read the last entry of all primary keys in a particular table. What is the SQL command for it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  A table has only one primary key, so what do you mean by "primary keys"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (primary_key) *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY primary_key, timestamp DESC;
```

This would return the record having the latest timestamp, for each primary key value.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your answer. This retrieves only the last entry of highest primary_key value. But, my requirement is to retrieve the last timestamp entry of all unique primary_keys values. Let's say I want to retrieve the order last order details of all existing customers in that table

Comment: @Deepak In that case, I recommend using `DISTINCT ON`, q.v. my updated answer.